# Decreasing metric counter value on RabbitMQ

Tags: rabbitmq, prometheus

I use RabbitMQ as a message broker to communicate with multiple computers and softwares and I enabled the plugin **rabbitmq_prometheus** in order to monitor the server.

I noticed that some metrics values have a very strange behaviour, like the metric **rabbitmq_channel_messages_delivered_ack_total** which is decreasing some times over time :
[metrics trend](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kM4VX.png)

My server is deployed on a Windows Server, I don't know if this can be linked to the OS.

I don't have any clue on what is happening but the decreasing of the counter is theoretically impossible so I was wondering if I was the only one that went through this issue ?

Comment: Do you have some aggregation on graphic showed on screenshot?

Comment: No there is no aggregation, the chart is displaying the raw values of the metrics rabbitmq_connection_outgoing_bytes_total

Comment: Counters indeed shouldn't do that. Couldn't it be that you are affected by [this issue](https://github.com/rabbitmq/rabbitmq-server/issues/2783)?

Comment: @markalex : Thanks for your feedback, yeah it seems to be related ! I will try to update my main server today and check if I still observe this issue.
I will keep you in touch.